# How to print two copies on single page from window print() using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-applications

I want to create two copies such as student copies and office copies on single page using java script windows print() function into asp.net with C#.
using windows print() function i get only one copies at time. its work very well
but get same print copies at two time.
ON button click i wont create two print copies on single page and single print code as below.
How can i resolved this issue.Please Help me as early as possible.
I am using asp.net 4.0 application on Web base  application Or project doing.
 i want two prints on single page like student cope and office cope..on one button click.. I create Receipt format using asp.net page on this page receipt no,tranid ,paid amt like that display ...this same Receipt I want create two time on sing page for student and office(copy Receipt )..using asp.net java script windows print function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('Button1').style.display = 'none';
        window.print();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: do you mean you want two copies on a single page? or are you saying you want to print two pages but it only prints one?

Comment: yes i want two prints on single page like student cope and office cope..on one button click.. I create Receipt format using asp.net page on this page receipt no,tranid ,paid amt like that display ...this same Receipt I want create two time on sing page for student and office(copy Receipt )..using asp.net java script windows print function